# How to force Jenkins to launch webpage/ cmd prompt in client (user's) machine?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

The job that I was trying to create in Jenkins would require launching a webpage **on the user’s browser** once the build is successful (Jenkins is installed on a remote server). For doing this I put the following line in the " Build - Execute Windows batch command" section of the job’s Configure page:

```
START http://google.com
```

While the build was successful, it did not launch the page. I have a hunch, this line will try to launch the webpage in the remote Jenkins server (it did not launch anything in the slave node though). My question is, how do I force the Jenkins job to launch the webpage in the **user’s default browser**?

I tried launching client's cmd.exe - this did not work either.

Jenkins master, slave, user's client - everything is on Windows. Jenkins version 1.46.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *"launch in client's machine"* you mean the user that is accessing the web interface of Jenkins? No, this won't happen. It can be quite a security risk too.

You can do what you are asking either on the master or the slave. Jenkins does not directly execute anything that is not on master/slave. It is possible to spawn a slave on user's machine, and when the job is run, it will execute the command on the slave.

Or if the user provides his/her computer IP address as a parameter to the job, you could use **[PsExec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897553.aspx)** to connect to user's computer to execute a command.

Comment: Thanks, @Slav. I understand it. Hope I can get a workaround somehow. Good day!